# How to install crystal report runtime in VS2008?

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-server

I am using VS2008 and I am building an Web Application with crystal report. As we know along with VS2008 we are provided crystal report basic version that is 10.5.0.0 with Crystal Report Runtime
version 10.5.0.0 .
When i try to deploy my website on server it gives me an error "Crystal Report not supported". And i got a reply from support that their server support Crystal Report Version 12.3.3.812 which is CR VS2008 SP3. 
And when i downloaded the version from SAP website, I am not able to upgrade my CR Version please let me know how to upgrade.

Comment: You can change the assembly versions in your web.config file to version 12.3.3.812.

or you can rollback to old version in the server itself.

Answer (score 1):

You need to upgrade your crystal reports version. You can download from
[SAP Official Wiki Site](https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/BOBJ/Crystal+Reports%2C+Developer+for+Visual+Studio+Downloads) or [Install Crystal reports developer version for Visual Studio](https://www.parthpatel.net/install-crystal-report-runtime/)

Comment: A link to documentation show that this is the cause of the issue would improve this answer :)

Comment: @OMGtechy didn't understand ;\

Answer (score 0):

To upgrade your machine you simply install the newer version of Crystal Reports on it.

To upgrade your project you'll need to remove the reference to the older bundled, free copy of Crystal Reports and add the newer 12.x references you should now see. (You'll see them only if you've successfully installed the newer Crystal Reports on this computer.)